# I'm trying to implement factorial in an xml language

Tags: factorial

I'm trying to implement factorial in the xml language of [xcerion](http://xcerion.com/).

```
     <step id="fac">
       <alias name="p" value="={$n}*{$p}" />
       <alias name="n" value="={$n}-1" />
       <operation name="decision">
         <when test="'{$n}'>'0'" step="fac" />
       </operation>
     </step>

     <alias name="p" value="1" />
     <alias name="n" value="4" />
     <operation name="call" value="fac" />
```

My code works, but I think it's a bit wordy.

How does this language compare with other xml languages?

Especially handling of variables, selection, loops and subroutine calling.

Comment: Using XML as the syntax base for a programming language is among the worst abuses I can imagine subjecting a maintenance developer to.

Comment: Many like the declarative route, but invariably face the need for custom logic.

Comment: Actually coding in a language that's been shoe-horned into valid XML... bonkers.  Saying you feel it's too wordy... priceless!

Comment: I suggest you ditch this language.

Comment: huh? In Xml, wow! Didn't think you could do that - in Xml, wordy, sounds more like needy - a sign of desperation...

Comment: anyone would like to see this closed as it is not a real question?

Comment: Ok, here is the question: Can anybody explain how Xcerion got 10 MUSD in risk money for this idea? http://xcerion.com/public-relations/press-release/xcerion-%11-xml-internet-os.../

Comment: @Kri-ban - this sentence intrigues/scares me the most from that article - `visual creation of software without programming`.

Comment: @Russ Cam - I agree. Programming is not easy, let's make it even more difficult by using xml, and telling everybody everybody can do it! 

XSLT and SSIS are other "good" examples of how things should NOT be done. Visual programming does not make it in a *dirty* reality.

Comment: Xcerion has got _fantastic_ reviews all over the world. See http://xcerion.com/press-coverage-2009/.

But, I can't find a single blog entry about the xml "programming" they enforce.

IMHO this product is *dead*.

The journalists did not do their job. Just looked at the fancy graphics.

Comment: +1 be honest. You just wanted to have the geeky satisfaction of posting this here.